python: ssl.wrap_socket - cert.pem vs. cert & key
I'm running SFTP server with the following code:
httpd= HTTPServer (('10.0.0.10',4443), MyHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, 
                keyfile='private.key',
                certfile='cert.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever ()

It's working fine.
As you can see, keyfile is 'None'.
Can you please tell what is the added value of using keyfile ?
Currently I need cert.pem is both server and client sides.
With keyfile I will need also keyfile at both sides.
My cert.pem contains:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID5zCCAs+gAwIBAgIURqxtwR4h5Byjj5139okUQhHdpL8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
...
Lsgcc6ild9ME6cmFhCKiIsdSaVQoNhU+lFC2Xu/1bZyYOGs4LgdfOXDfog==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Your cert.pem contains the private key as well as the certificate. If you wanted to put each in a separate file, then you could point to the private key file with keyfile=. Also, SFTP is a file transfer protocol that runs over the SSH protocol. It has nothing to do with SSL. If you've distributed your private key to others than you've compromised that private key and need to start over.

Thank you very much for your comment.  Can you please tell what is the best secured way with this SFTP server ?  My customer gets a PC that runs the SFTP server and an embedded PC that runs an SFTP client (wget). He does not have access to cert.pem

This is not an SFTP server. wget is not an SFTP client.

I created cert.pem without private key and also a separate private key.  In the client side, in what scenario should I use: wget --ca-certificate=cert.pem and also --private-key=private.key ?
